# Destructor for Angular 1.5 Service

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular 1.5 service that wraps a SignalR proxy. When the Angular app is destroyed, I'd like to explicitly leave all SignalR groups that the user has registered for rather than waiting on the explicit SignalR timeout.

I know that with Angular 1.5x controllers, I can listen for:

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function handler() { ... });
```

But I am not sure how I "clean up" within a service and release resources I no longer need. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Services are singleton in Angular, so they don't have destroy like method.
I don't familiar with SignalR but if they have unsubscribe like method, you should call this method when you don't need the listeners.

Comment: @FunnStuff, that's the rub - I need the SignalR channels open until the user is done with the app and navigates away from the domain or closes the browser.

Comment: So you can listen to window onbeforeunload event - Execute a JavaScript when the page is about to be unloaded (close)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a cleaning function in your service and call it when you [$destroy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy) the controller.

```
scope.$on('$destroy', function() { ... });
```

In angular 1.5 you also have [$onDestroy](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) in your components.

However, you can't always bet that `$destroy` will be called (lets say user kills the browser process), so you will also need to provide some solution from your server side.

Comment: Since services are singletons and live for the entire life of the AngularJS application, we cannot reliably call a destructor function within a service whenever a controller is destroyed. A controller may be instantiated and destroyed many times within the life of an Angular app, but a service will be instantiated once and the singleton reference reused by the injector. Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: `we cannot reliably call a destructor function within a service whenever a controller is destroyed` you should not "destroy" the service, you only need to terminate the resource that the service provides you. you can use an atomic flag to determinate if the service currently serves the resource or not.

[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131691/angular-using-server-sent-events-in-a-factory) helped me to setup server send events stream in an angular application